# href onclick javascript right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a function in JavaScript something like

```
function continents(post_id,continent,countries){
   location.href="/serv/continent.php?param="+post_id+"&"+continent+"/"+countries;
}
```

and then I have a anchor tag in my php page

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="continents('<?php echo $row['sno']; ?>','<?php echo $url_con_name; ?>','<?php echo $url_contries; ?>')" >
   <div>some date here </div>
</a>
```

Now the link is working fine but when I right click on that link I don't find **open link in new tab** and **open link in new window**.

How can I solve this without removing the function.

Comment: Remove `href="javascript: void(0)"` and what you have got in rendered `HTML` ?

Comment: How about

    `<a href="/serv/continent.php?param=<?php echo $row['sno'], '&', $url_con_name, '/', $url_contries ?>">`

Comment: @Musa thanks it worked, i have tried it before similar to yours but something went wrong, now its fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no href attribute in your `a` tag, therefore there is *no link* to open.

The fix is to put a proper URL in your href attribute.

Since you are using jQuery, you likely shouldn't be using onclick attributes anyways.

Do something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/proper/link" id="myLink">
```

Then attach the JS logic via jQuery:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault() 
        // this will prevent the link from loading the 
        // href value upon click, but still leave it 
        // accessible to right-click contextual menu.
    the rest of your JS logic here...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `href="#"` and onclick event has `return false;`

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="continents('<?php echo $row['sno']; ?>','<?php echo $url_con_name; ?>','<?php echo $url_contries; ?>'); return false;" >
<div>some date here </div></a>
```

Comment: there still is no proper href attribute, so you won't get the options in the contextual menu.

Comment: @DA. I tried http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/ykeLF/, it shows the contextual menu.

Comment: Right, but all it will be is the current URL + #, so likely not what the OP intends (as there is little reason to open the same page in a new tab)